# Is it unethical to not disclose relationship when applying to same group

Tags: phd, etiquette, europe, conflict-of-interest, two-body-problem

My girlfriend and I are applying to the same PhD program and are interested in the same group. The group is quite small and it is likely that we will be working together a lot, I am unsure if mentioning the relationship is the right thing to do.

In my country it is illegal to be discriminated against because of a relationship within the workplace (If one doesn't let it affect the working relationship).
The code of conduct of the institution states that they do not discriminate against existing relations, and only that relationships between supervisors and their employees need to be disclosed.

Given the size of the group it feels wrong to me, not to mention the relationship to the potential supervisor. Yet, given that only a few people are admitted I fear that this would lessen the chances of both being accepted as it is just more potential for conflict.

Comment: This seems like the sort of question that would be difficult to answer without knowing the country, or at least the part of the world.

Comment: @cag51 This. And also the institution. Some institutions have very strict rules, others, not so. Unfortunately, legal wants to protect from all vagaries of life, squashing life itself in the process.

Comment: On the risk side for you (and your girlfriend): what happens if you split up?

Comment: @cag51 It is in europe and the only rules I am aware of are the ones I pointed out

Comment: @JonCuster I guess that is why it seems unethical to me not to disclose. As that might have an impact on the work relation

Comment: Anyway, you need a plan for the situation where the two of you don’t get into the same program.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are putting conditions on the hiring, I see no ethical need to inform the institution. There is no conflict of interest in the hiring process, though it might arise later.

If you won't accept an offer unless both are accepted or if you won't accept an offer unless both are placed in the same group, then you should inform them. But if you are flexible about it then you are just two people applying for positions.

Working together isn't a conflict unless there is some competition involved.

If you are both accepted to the program then you can both apply to the group, at which point disclosure would seem necessary.

This is the classic two-body problem. It is sometimes helpful, however, to disclose a relationship when it is necessary for both to be "hired". Useful because if one of you is very highly desired then the other's qualifications might not be quite the same issue as otherwise. That is a judgement call for you and ultimately a judgement call for them.

Note that I've assumed that applying to the program and applying to the group are distinct. If it is the same, then earlier disclosure might be required and whether it works for or against you depends on a lot of judgements. But if you won't accept an offer from one but not the other, then you should say so to avoid forcing people to waste time unproductively in the process. In a small group, I'd guess it works against you unless the group is expanding (or willing to expand).

And, advice not asked for: the two-body problem can often be solved by applying to places that have a lot of nearby universities. That often means large metropolitan areas, of course, which can be expensive or involve a lot of commuting effort. And, working at nearby universities doesn't foreclose the possibility of working together, necessarily, though that is more true for faculty than doctoral students.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I don't necessarily agree that it is the two body problem. We are just both applying, we do not put any condition on the hiring, nor do we noth apply there so that we can work/be together. We just both like the work that group is doing, and we'll see what happens. Although the application is for "grad school" one picks an advisor upfront.